# Is it useful to use VZEROUPPER if your program+libraries contain no SSE instructions?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, avx, micro-optimization

I understand it's important to use `VZEROUPPER` when mixing SSE and AVX code but what if I only use AVX (and ordinary x86-64 code) without using any legacy SSE instructions?

If I never use a single SSE instruction in my code, is there any performance reason why I would ever need to use `VZEROUPPER`?

This is assuming I'm not calling into any external libraries (that might be using SSE).

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/704023 *VZEROUPPER was used for avoiding the cost of this state transition by clearing the upper half of all the registers* I think the CPUs don't know which instructions you're using and whether the state transition logic is necessary, just that `VZEROUPPER` means that it's not necessary. Admittedly I am not particularly qualified in this area, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I'm not sure what your point is, but of course the CPU knows what instructions you're using; it's the thing that executes them.  And if you don't use any SSE instructions, there are no state transitions (except on context switches), you can just stay in the dirty-upper state indefinitely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See also [First use of AVX 256-bit vectors slows down 128-bit vector and AVX scalar ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874161/first-use-of-avx-256-bit-vectors-slows-down-128-bit-vector-and-avx-scalar-ops) re: implicit widening of 128-bit AVX operations to 256-bit if any uppers are dirty.  (Including for the purposes of ["light" vs. "heavy" turbo limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency)).  This could be a reason to use `vzeroupper`, especially if you have some regions of your program that use 256-bit vectors (especially "light" instructions, like integer stuff other than multiply), and others that make heavy use of 128-bit FMA.  Without `vzeroupper`, the 128-bit FP math instructions could lower your max turbo as if you'd been using heavy 256-bit instructions. (If you're doing that anyway, maybe not a big deal).

---

You're correct that if your whole program doesn't use *any* non-VEX instructions that write `xmm` registers, you don't need `vzeroupper` to avoid state-transition penalties.

Beware that non-VEX instructions can lurk in CRT startup code and/or the dynamic linker, or other highly non-obvious places.

That said, a non-VEX instruction can only cause a one-time penalty when it runs.  The reverse isn't true: one VEX-256 instruction can make non-VEX instructions in general (or just with that register) [slow for the rest of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake/41349852#41349852).

---

There's [no penalty when mixing VEX and EVEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080327/what-is-the-penalty-of-mixing-evex-and-vex-encoded-scheme), so no need to use `vzeroupper` there.

---

**On Skylake-AVX512: `vzeroupper` or `vzeroall` are the only way to restore max-turbo after dirtying a ZMM register**, assuming your program still uses any SSE*, AVX1, or AVX2  instructions on xmm/ymm0..15.

See also [Does Skylake need vzeroupper for turbo clocks to recover after a 512-bit instruction that only reads a ZMM register, writing a k mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568514/does-skylake-need-vzeroupper-for-turbo-clocks-to-recover-after-a-512-bit-instruc) - merely reading a zmm doesn't cause this.

> Posted by [@BeeOnRope in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43768745#43768745):

> There is a new, pretty bad effect with AVX-512 instructions on surrounding code: once a 512-bit instruction is executed (except perhaps for instructions that don't write to a zmm register) the core enters an "upper 256 dirty state". In this state, any later scalar FP/SSE/AVX instruction (anything using xmm or ymm regs) will internally be extended to 512 bits. This means the processor will be locked to no higher than the AVX turbo (the so-called "L1 license") until vzeroupper or vzeroall are issued.
>
> Unlike the earlier "dirty upper 128" issue with AVX and legacy non-VEX SSE (which still exists on Skylake Xeon), this will slow down all code due to the lower frequency, but there are no "merging uops" or false dependencies or anything like that: it's just that the smaller operations are effectively treated as 512-bit wide in order to implement the zero-extending behavior.
>
> about "writing the low halves ..." - **no, it is a global state, and only vzero* gets you out of it**. It occurs even if you dirty a zmm register but use different ones for ymm and xmm. It occurs even if the only dirtying instruction is a zeroing idiom like `vpxord zmm0, zmm0, zmm0`. **It doesn't occur for writes to zmm16-31 though**.

His description of *actually* extending all vector ops to 512 bits isn't quite right, because he later confirmed that it doesn't reduce throughput for 128 and 256-bit instructions.  But we know that when 512-bit uops are in flight, the vector ALUs on port 1 are shut down.  (So the 256-bit FMA units normally accessible via ports 0 and 1 can combine into a 512-bit unit for all FP math, integer multiply, and possibly some other stuff.  Some SKX Xeons have a 2nd 512-bit FMA unit on port 5, some don't.)

---

**For max-turbo after using only AVX1 / AVX2** (including on earlier CPUs like Haswell): Opportunistically powering down the upper halves of execution units if they haven't been used for a while (and sometimes allowing higher Turbo clock speeds) depends on whether YMM instructions have been used recently, not on whether the upper halves are dirty or not.  So AFAIK, `vzeroupper` does *not* help the CPU un-throttle the clock speed sooner after using AVX1 / AVX2, for CPUs where max turbo is lower for 256-bit.

This is different from Intel's Skylake-AVX512 (SKX / Skylake-SP), where AVX512 is somewhat "bolted on".

---

#### `VZEROUPPER` might make context switches *slightly* cheaper

because the CPU still knows whether the ymm-upper state is clean or dirty.

If it's clean, I think [`xsaveopt`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/XSAVEOPT) or `xsavec` can write out the FPU state more compactly, without storing the all-zero upper halves at all (just setting a bit that says they're clean).  Notice [in the state-transition diagram for SSE/AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake/41349852#41349852) that `xsave` / `xrstor` is part of the picture.

An extra `vzeroupper` just for this is only worth considering if your code won't use any 256b instructions for a *long* time after this, because ideally you won't have any context switches / CPU migrations before the next use of 256-bit vectors.

This may not apply as much on AVX512 CPUs: `vzeroupper` / [`vzeroall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vzeroall#vzeroall--vex-256-encoded-version-) don't touch ZMM16..31, only ZMM0..15.  So you can still have lots of dirty state after `vzeroall`.

---

(Plausible in theory): **Dirty upper halves may be taking up physical registers** (although IDK of any evidence for this being true on any real CPUs).  If so, it would limit out-of-order window size for the CPU to find instruction-level parallelism.  (ROB size is the other major limiting factor, [but PRF size can be the bottleneck](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/).)

This may be true on AMD CPUs before Zen2, where 256b ops are split into two 128b ops.  YMM registers are handled internally as two 128-bit registers, and e.g. `vmovaps ymm0, ymm1` renames the low 128 with zero latency, but needs a uop for the upper half.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  It's unknown whether `vzeroupper` can actually drop the renaming for the upper halves, though.  Zeroing idioms on AMD Zen (unlike SnB-family) still need a back-end uop to write the register value, even for the 128b low half; only mov-elimination avoids a back-end uop.  So there may not be a physical zero register that uppers can be renamed onto.

Experiments in that ROB size / PRF size [blog post](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/) show that FP physical register file entries are 256-bit in Sandybridge, though.  `vzeroupper` shouldn't free up more registers on mainstream Intel CPUs with AVX/AVX2.  Haswell-style transition penalties are slow enough that it probably drains the ROB to save or restore uppers to separate storage that isn't renamed, not using up valuable PRF entries.

Silvermont doesn't support AVX.  And it uses [a separate retirement register file](https://www.realworldtech.com/silvermont/4/) for the architectural state, so the out-of-order PRF only holds speculative execution results.  So even if it did support AVX with 128-bit halves, a stale YMM register with a dirty upper half probably wouldn't be using up extra space in the rename register file.

KNL (Knight's Landing / Xeon Phi) is specifically designed to run AVX512, so presumably its FP register file has 512-bit entries.  It's based on Silvermont, but the SIMD parts of the core are different (e.g. it can reorder FP/vector instructions, while Silvermont can only execute them speculatively but not reorder them within the FP/vector pipeline, according to Agner Fog).  Still, KNL may also use a separate retirement register file, so dirty ZMM uppers wouldn't consume extra space even if it was able to split a 512-bit entry to store two 256-bit vectors.  Which is unlikely, because a larger out-of-order window for only AVX1/AVX2 on KNL wouldn't be worth spending transistors on.

**`vzeroupper` is much slower on KNL than mainstream Intel CPUs (one per 36 cycles in 64-bit mode)**, so you probably wouldn't want to use, especially just for the tiny context-switch advantage.

---

On Skylake-AVX512, the evidence supports the conclusion that the vector physical register file is 512-bits wide.

Some future CPU might pair up entries in a physical register file to store wide vectors, even if they don't normally decode to separate uops the way AMD does for 256-bit vectors.

[@Mysticial reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892733/can-avx2-compiled-program-still-use-32-registers-of-an-avx-512-capable-cpu#comment84791900_48892842) unexpected slowdowns in code with long FP dependency chains with YMM vs. ZMM but otherwise identical code, but later experiments disagree with the conclusion that SKX uses 2x 256-bit register file entries for ZMM registers when the upper 256 bits are dirty.

---

#### AVX-512 and physical registers on Ice Lake / Sapphire Rapids

https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/01/15/golden-coves-vector-register-file-checking-with-official-spr-data/

> [...]
> While testing on server Ice Lake suggests Intel’s mechanism isn’t nearly that sophisticated. Instead, the core simply remembers whether the upper set of ZMM registers are in use. **If you use any of the extra registers introduced with AVX-512 – that is, ZMM16 through 31, Ice Lake reserves another 16 registers to hold known-good state.** It doesn’t matter if you touch one of them or all of them. Golden Cove is Ice Lake’s successor, and could use a similar mechanism.
>
> ...
> Therefore, Zen 4 does not employ the same register-saving optimization as Ice Lake.

But unfortunately, I don't think `vzeroupper` / `vzeroall` can help with this; it doesn't affect ZMM16..31, so it can't restore them to "clean" status and free up those extra 16 physical registers for out-of-order exec.

If I understand correctly, manually xor-zeroing them *will* stop them from using physical registers (`vpxord xmm16, xmm16, xmm16` through xmm31); either there's an extra bit to indicate all-zero, or there's a physical zero register that the renamer can point them at.  But there might still be 16 extra PRF entries reserved for retirement state, even if the actual RAT entries aren't pointing at them.

With them zeroed, `xsave`/`xrstor` on context-switch might get back to the zmm16-31-unused state.  The CPU presumably has to be able to get back to that state somehow other than a cold boot or entering a deep sleep state.

That article has some other interesting findings, like that only 220 of the 320 vector PRF entries are capable of holding 512-bit results.  So using 256-bit instructions whenever that's sufficient (e.g. horizontal reductions start by narrowing to 256) can help out-of-order exec see farther ahead.

Comment: The same [stuffedcow](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/) blog entry you linked above indicates that the physical register file is at 256-bit wide since Sandy Bridge. See [this comment](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/comment-page-1/#comment-4354) and also Fig. 7 which seems like it wouldn't be possible if the SIMD speculative register entries on SnB were limited to `120/2 = 60`.

Comment: Although you are no doubt aware, you may want to add for the benefit for the OP that _whole program_ really means whole program. It can be hard to avoid non-VEX code entirely, since even things like the dynamic linker and standard libraries may use it (the former being harder to avoid than the latter). That said, I don't think there is a particular problem with mostly-VEX processes with the occasional non-VEX code: the non-VEX code either runs slowly (Skylake+) or your suffer state transitions (Haswell-), but neither matters if you have a small amount of non-VEX code.

Comment: The reverse isn't true: if you are using non-VEX code in your application and you get a single VEX instruction, on Skylake+ you will suffer a [permanent penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41349852/149138) in your SSE code because the strategy for mixed code changed (at least until you get lucky enough to get an effective `vzeroupper` from somewhere else like a context switch).

Comment: re: "But we know that when 512-bit uops are in flight, the vector ALUs on port 1 are shut down" is this correct? [Agner Fog writes](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=153) "The Skylake-X supports the AVX512 instruction set. There are two 256-bit vector execution
units at port 0 and 1, respectively. These two units can be combined into one 512-bit unit
when 512-bit vector instructions are executed. This combined 512-bit unit is accessed
through port 0, while port 1 can be used for other purposes simultaneously." which makes it sound like p1 will NOT be shutdown.

Comment: @Noah: I said the *vector* ALUs on port 1.  The scalar-integer ALUs on p1 are still active so instructions like `imul` and `popcnt` still have somewhere to run. :P  (And it can of course still run other single-cycle latency scalar instructions like `add`.)  But not uops like `pand xmm,xmm`.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I took Agner Fog's sentence to mean hypothetically you run an ```AVX512``` instruction on p0 along side another vector instruction on p1. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Noah: No, it's not.  That vector ALU might already be busy running half of a 512-bit uop, and it would be hard for the scheduler to check that when scheduling uops, without making it cost even more power.

Comment: @PeterCordes based on [this glibc thread](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-March/124450.html) it seems as of now Linux expects to save the entire state on context switch irrelivant of the what has been used. With [amx](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/x86/amx) though they seem to have a need to implement that optimization but as of now don't seem present.

Comment: Avoiding `vzeroupper` by using `zmm16..31` apparently makes sense in context of Intel RTM. [a comment in MS DevCom site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Make-compiler-avoid-generation-of-VZeroU/828433#T-N839323) says that dirty uppers flag causes RTM transaction about, and for zmm16..31 this is avoided.

Comment: @PeterCordes here the wording can be made stronger. `vzeroupper` does save time/space on context switches as it clears the `ZMM_Hi256 state` flag (I would imagine `SSE_state` and `AVX_state` but I haven't tested). But note that for xmm/ymm/zmm16-31 once they have been touched it appears they are tracked for the remainder of the program (by context switches at least). The [modified optimization](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf#page=324) may be able help a bit though.